# Problem reconnecting Dell latitude to docking station

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, dell, docking

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with i3wm on a Dell Latitude E7450 that I connect to a docking station Dell F310c. I have two monitors connected the station and on boot everything works correctly.

The problem is that when I take the computer from the station and I put back I have to log off and log in again in order to get the two extern monitors to work again. xrandr tells me that the monitors are connected:

```
bernahec@cronopio~$
|
15:30--->xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5520 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+3600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  59.93    47.99  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1-1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.88*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
DP1-2 connected 1920x1080+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      59.98  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

But when I rerun xrandr in order to connect to the screens nothing happens. Using --verbose I get the following output:

```
bernahec@cronopio~$
|
15:34--->xrandr --verbose --output eDP1 --right-of DP1-2 --output DP1-1 --left-of DP1-2
crtc 0:    1920x1080  60.02 +3600+0 "eDP1"
```

Do someone know if there is a daemon I can restart instead of login off and in again? Or any Idea about how to debug the issue? I can't find anything in dmesg, kern.log or syslog that helps me.